# PM2 How to start nextjs project in prod mode?

Tags: next.js, deployment, pm2

I want to run a project in pm2.

My folder structure:

[image: folder]

My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 7777",
    "type-check": "tsc",
    "gensitemap": "node generate-sitemap.mjs",
    "prod": "yarn && npm run build && npm run start"
  },
```

My ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'core',
      script: 'yarn --cwd core prod',
      watch: false,
    },
  ],
};
```

When, I started `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`
I got the following error in the logs
`error - Invalid project directory provided, no such directory: D:\React\MyProject\src\core\prod`

I tried different ways to run in production mode.
It came out only in dev mode to run

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "prod mode"? What differences are you expecting between dev & prod mode? Your question is a bit vague as of now. Do you intend to run your `npm run prod` command using pm2?

Answer (score 0):

With **PM2** it isn't important to use ***ecosystem.config.js***. Just add waht command do you want in **package.json** file like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "prod": "yarn && npm run build && npm run start"
     .
     .
     .   
  
  }
```

Then run **pm2 command**:

***DEV***

```
pm2 start "pm2 run dev" --name YOUR_APP_NAME -- start
```

***PROD***

```
pm2 start "pm2 run prod" --name YOUR_APP_NAME -- start
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using nextjs, try use the code below.
script is changed

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'core',
      script: "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      watch: false,
    },
  ],
};
```